# How to skip empty String with mustache

Tags: java, mustache, jstachio

I want a text like

If Romeo contains Text.

- Alpha
- Romeo
- //empty line
- //empty line
- Julia

If Romeo is Null or Empty

- Alpha
- Julia

My .mustache looks like

```
 {{alpha}}
 {{#romeo}}{{romeo}}\n\n{{/romeo}}
 {{julia}}
```

This workis for the case romeo is null. But not when romeo is an empty string. Is it possible to fix that without changing backends input like

```
if(romeo.isEmpty()){
  romeo=null;
```

Comment: IIRC, you can use `{{-#romeo}} ... {{/romeo-}}` (or maybe `~` instead of `-`), though it is possible that was in Handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this without configuring what is "falsey" which is not available in all mustache implementations is to use the dotted chain break feature of mustache.

I'm going to use [JStachio](https://github.com/jstachio/jstachio) to demo this but this should work in JMustache as well but probably not for mustache.java as it does not have consistent whitespace handling:

```java
@JStache(template = """
        {{alpha}}
        {{^romeo.empty}}
        {{#romeo}}
        {{romeo}}


        {{/romeo}}
        {{/romeo.empty}}
        {{julia}}
        """)
public record SkipEmptyStrings(String alpha, String romeo, String julia) {
}
```

Notice how we still had to check if romeo existed or not because of inverted path rules. That is an inverted path will succeed even if romeo is null.

```java
    @Test
    public void testRomeo() {
        SkipEmptyStrings e = new SkipEmptyStrings("Alpha", "Romeo", "Julia");
        String actual = JStachio.render(e);
        String expected = """
                Alpha
                Romeo


                Julia
                """;
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testRomeoNull() {
        SkipEmptyStrings e = new SkipEmptyStrings("Alpha", null, "Julia");
        String actual = JStachio.render(e);
        String expected = """
                Alpha
                Julia
                """;
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRomeoEmpty() {
        SkipEmptyStrings e = new SkipEmptyStrings("Alpha", "", "Julia");
        String actual = JStachio.render(e);
        String expected = """
                Alpha
                Julia
                """;
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```